# Google maps sdk android markers click listener not working

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-markers, kotlin-android-extensions

i'm trying to place markers with custom icon and colors. Currently working in kotlin for android. I am trying to set markers on click listener as stated in docs of google. But on click nothing is happening.

overidden the function onMarkerClick and tried to get tag of that marker as i stored in that and before that i treid to use .equal method to test that if the marker is equal to that event marker

```
override fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker): Boolean {

        // Retrieve the data from the marker.
        var clickCount = marker.tag as Int?

        // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
        if (clickCount != null) {
            clickCount = clickCount!! + 1
            marker.tag = clickCount
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                marker.title +
                        " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
        // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
        // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
        return false
    }


    mMap = googleMap
            val streetRight = mMap.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions().position(
                    LatLng(
                        -xx.xxxxx,
                        xxx.xxxxxx
                    )
                ).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_street_view_person))
            )
            val streeTop = mMap.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions().position(
                    LatLng(
                        -xx.xxxxx,
                        xxx.xxxxxx
                    )
                ).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_street_view_person))
            )
    streeTop.tag = 1
            streetRight.tag = 2
```

I expect that when i click on marker it should show a toast that marker is clicked. But nothing happens just map centers that marker.

Comment: Debug your code and put a breakpoint in this line ` var clickCount = marker.tag as Int?` If this lined reacted then the `clickCount` is null.

Comment: @MahmoudShahoud yes it is reacting

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your code working, but I added the listener to onMapReady:

```
   override fun onMapReady(gMap: GoogleMap?) {
        gMap?.let {
             it.setOnMarkerClickListener {
                var clickCount = it.tag as Int?

                // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
                if (clickCount != null) {
                    clickCount = clickCount!! + 1
                    it.tag = clickCount
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MapFragment.context,
                        it.title +
                                " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }

                // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
                // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
                // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
                false
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets called after you call .getMapAsync()